# Does html option supports mouseover events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have following HTML.

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

When the user clicks on select input, dropdown opens with option 1, 2 & 3. Now let's say user moves the mouse over option 2. Is there an HTML event which can be used to detect that user has hovered on option 2?

I tried with `mouseenter` event, it only works when `select` tag is marked as `<select multiple>`. For single value it doesn't work.

Comment: Try onmouseover: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: There's no hover/mouse movement related events raised from `option` elements, so what you're attempting is not possible. The marked duplicate is outdated and no longer works.